# How to add badge on navigation drawer item

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in my application where I set icon and text with menu.How can I add a badge on my icon like showed in image? I have tried another answers but I can only set a badge next to text.

[image]

Here is my navigation view

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:theme="@style/NavigationViewSeparator"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorDrawerText"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header_layout"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_divider"
            app:itemIconPadding="17dp"
            app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawer"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorBlack"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer"/>
```

And my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_near_by"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_nearby_icon"
            android:title="@string/search" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_contacts"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts_icon"
            android:title="@string/contact_list"/>

    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: it's a navigation drawer not a bottom navigation view

Answer (score 0):

You should define a specific layout for your menu item, composed of view with id. So when you will need to hide the badge, it is pretty easy.

Here is an item example with an action layout :

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notification"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_toolbar_notification"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_toolbar_notification"
        app:showAsAction="always"  />
```

Here is my actionLayout (image + badge) :

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:focusable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notification" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/notif_badge"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_gravity="right|end"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_shape" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Then you can grab menu element from your code and hide notif badge if needed :

```
final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
notif_badge = actionView.findViewById(R.id.notif_badge);
// DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH NOTIF_BADGE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this approach  but the action layout is set after the text, on the right of my row. Is there a way to put the action layout item on the right like in attached pic?

Comment: Did you put actionLayout on an item in a menu? (which you inflates in your nav drawer afterwards)

Comment: can you link a picture of result?